# How to execute a command with backslashes in go

Tags: go, output, exec

I want to return the output of an app version using go

Why does the below fail?

```
emulatorCmd := exec.Command(`mdls`, `-name`, `kMDItemVersion`, `/Applications/Bot\`, `Framework\`, `Emulator.app`)
emulatorVersion, err := emulatorCmd.Output()
if err != nil {                      
   log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed in emulator", err)                       
   fmt.Println("Looks like you don't have the Bot Emulator installed yet, download here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v4.5.2")
} else {
   fmt.Println("Emulator:", string(emulatorVersion))

}
```

Giving:

```
cmd.Run() failed in emulator%!(EXTRA *exec.ExitError=exit status 1)
```

But when I replace the command with an app that has no spaces in the name (thus, doesn't require backslashes) like

```
exec.Command(`mdls`, `-name`, `kMDItemVersion`, `/Applications/FaceTime.app`)
```

It's successful, giving:

```
Emulator: kMDItemVersion = "5.0"
```

I tried putting it all in one string, but spaces in the command need to be separated by a comma. Also tried using two '\' backslashes and now even using back ticks does not work.

Also looked at the go string literals page but didn't find something relevant to this problem:
https://golang.org/ref/spec#raw_string_lit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes you need in command line are to escape the spaces to prevent them from being treated as argument separators *by the shell*. Since there is no shell involved executing this way in Go, you don't need them. You can just:

```
exec.Command(`mdls`, `-name`, `kMDItemVersion`, `/Applications/Bot Framework Emulator.app`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried that, but the output is the same error because spaces must be separated by a comma

Comment: What do you mean "spaces must be separated by a comma"? Are you sure you've tried it exactly as quoted in the answer? Also, have you tried actually *printing the error you receive* to see the specific error?

Comment: so if you want to run the command `git -v` it needs to be separated like `cmd := exec.Command("git", "-v")`. Similarly here. I want to run `mdls -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Bot\ Framework\ Emulator.app` so it must be separated like have in the first block of code in my question.

Comment: also edited my question to show the explicit error and did try again exactly what you input

Comment: No, it really doesn't. You need to separate *arguments*, completely regardless of the *spaces*. You have an argument which contains spaces; *in a shell*, you would have to enclose that argument in quotes or escape the spaces with backslashes. You aren't using a shell here though, so you need do neither.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what was going wrong. I tried it once more now and it worked. Thanks for your help